# Pygame moving image not appearing on moving background

Tags: python, background, pygame, character

So, i have a moving background for my pygame that is working fine. Now i wanted to add an obstacle (like a rock), that would be at the bottom of the screen and would move with the background. However, the image (obstacle) just disapears after appearing for a couple of seconds. I want the rock to appear over and over, however, it does not appear. Cant figure out whats wrong. Plz help, thanks!

```
background = pygame.image.load('background.png')
backgroundX = 0
backgroundX2 = background.get_width()
obstacle = pygame.image.load('obstacle.png')
obstacleX = 0
obstacleX2 = obstacle.get_width()


# use procedure for game window rather than using it within loop
def redrawGameWindow():
    # background images for right to left moving screen
    screen.blit(background, (backgroundX, 0))
    screen.blit(background, (backgroundX2, 0))
    man.draw(screen)
    screen.blit(obstacle, (obstacleX, 380))
    screen.blit(obstacle, (obstacleX2, 380))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
```

The main loop:

```
while run:
    screen.fill(white)
    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.display.update()
    redrawGameWindow()  # call procedure

    obstacleX -= 1.4
    obstacleX2 -= 1.4

    if obstacleX < obstacle.get_width() * -10:
        obstacleX = obstacle.get_width

    if obstacleX2 < obstacle.get_width() * -10:
        obstacleX2 = obstacle.get_width()
```

Comment: Please elaborate , thanks :)

Comment: i tried to show the updates through redrawGameWindow. how should i do it instead? thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `surface.blit()` (i.e.: screen.blit) function takes an image and top-left co-ordinates of where to draw it.

In the code provided the two copies of `obstacle` are drawn at `obstacleX` and `obstacleX2` - one of which is set to `0`, and the other the width of the image.  So this should result in the two images being drawn next to each other, on the left side of the window, at line 380.

If these images are no longer being drawn after a while, this could be caused by -

- The variables `obstacleX` and `obstacleX2` being changed to an off-screen position
- The image `obstacle` being changed to a blank (or otherwise invisible) version

There is no evidence in the small code sample above, but since the question suggests the images move, it's my guess that the `obstacleX` and `obstacleX2` co-ordinates of the drawing positions are being changed to become off-screen.

EDIT:

It's apparent that your objects are starting at position `0` (window left), and the position is being updated `obstacleX -= 1.4` which is moving the obstacle *further left*.  This is why they start on-screen, but soon disappear.

Put your screen dimensions into constants, e.g.:

```
WINDOW_WIDTH  = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400
```

And use these instead of peppering your code with numbers.  This reduces the number of changes needed if you decide to change window sizes, and it also allows calculations based on window width.

So start your obstacle just off the screen.

```
obstacleX  = WINDOW_WIDTH          # off-screen
obstacleX2 = WINDOW_WIDTH + 100    # Further away from first obstacle
```

In the main update-loop, when the position of the items change, check to see if they need to be re-cycled back to in-front of the player:

```
# Move the obstacles 1-pixel to the left
obstacleX  -= 1.4
obstacleX2 -= 1.4   # probably just 1 would be better  

# has the obstacle gone off-screen (to the left)
if ( obstacleX < 0 - obstacle.get_width() ):   
    # move it back to the right (off-screen)
    obstacleX = WINDOW_WIDTH + random.randint( 10, 100 )  

# TODO - handle obstacleX2 similarly
```

Comment: thanks!! but how should i change it? should i change the variable names or move them to a diff location? and yes, the images move :) thanks!

Comment: @User - Well, How do you want it to work?  What happens with the obstacles when they move off-screen?  Do they come back later?  A different one comes?  A simple change would be to re-set the `obstacleX` variable to 0 when it becomes at a position which is greater than the width of the window (assuming it moves left->right).  Put the check in where the code updates the obstacle's position.

Comment: the objective of my game is to have the screen move from left to right, and then there is a character that has to jump over obstacles. the obstacles also move from left to right with the screen. the screens animations have been going fine but the obstacle that my character is supposed to jump over keeps disappearing...not sure why. its kind of like that game u play when theres no wifi(t rex game)

Comment: OH I ALSO HAVE THIS CODE (totally forgot to add it - sorry!!)

Comment: if obstacleX < obstacle.get_width() * -10:
        obstacleX = obstacle.get_width

    if obstacleX2 < obstacle.get_width() * -10:
        obstacleX2 = obstacle.get_width()

Comment: @User - Why is that `* -10` ?   Say the image is 64 pixels wide, this test becomes:  `if obstacleX < -640`.  If the object moves from left to right, the `x` co-ordinate is increasing, from say 0 to window-width... right?  Please edit your question to include the code that changes `obstacleX` to make the bitmap move.

Comment: thanks for the edit, i didnt know how to edit my question so i didnt change it that time (new to this)

Comment: so what value should i change -10 into

Comment: @User - Please see refer to answer above.